# Hurt someone and say "sorry" - Is there a word to describe this type of behaviour and/or people?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests

People unintentionally hurt others whilst in the middle of an argument, it could happen anywhere: in public or even in the privacy of one's bedroom. When they finally realize their mistake, they end up saying *sorry* etc., etc.

Are such people categorized in a dictionary? Is there a word for such people and such a situation?

Comment: Are you asking whether there is a word to categorize those people who unintentionally hurt other people and then say they are sorry?  If so, the answer is yes -- we call such people "**people**".

Comment: @Drew Just label us all social inepts, why don't you.

Answer (score 2):

I would say ***[apologetic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/apologetic)***:

> Expressing or showing regretful acknowledgement of an offence or failure:
>
> *she was very apologetic about the whole incident*

---

Also they are ***[guilt-ridden](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/guilt-ridden)***:

> feeling or revealing a sense of guilt

Comment: Both these are describing someone actually feeling remorseful at the moment.  Is the OP looking for a word to describe people who behave like that in general, e.g. "I like John, although we have lively discussions he's x [= he's concerned with my feelings and feels bad and apologises when he realises he's hurt them."?